# Доступ к данным из статического класса

Tags: php, алгоритм, ооп

Есть родитель:

```
class Main{

    protected $a = "SUCCESS";

    public function foo(){
        echo $this->a;
    }
}

$Main = new Main();
// $Main->foo();
```

Есть наследник:

```
require_once("Main.php");

class Child extends Main{

    public static function Run(){
        echo parent::$a;
    }
}
Child::Run();
```

Строчка `echo parent::$a;` говорит, что `$a` не является статической. Я не могу ее сделать статической, так как везде она вызывается через объект: `$this->..` .

Бывают случаи, когда к главному классу проекта нужно прикрутить статические классы (ничего не меняя в главном). Как, собственно, получить доступ из потомка к данным родителя, при условии того, что потомок является статическим?

Answer (score 1):

Можно передать в статический метод наследника экземпляр родительского объекта:

```
// require_once("Main.php");
class Child extends Main{
    public static function Run($Instance){
        ob_start();
        $Instance->foo();
        $aa = ob_get_clean();
        printf( "My \$a: %s\n", $aa);
    }
}

Child::Run( $Main);
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/X1iMji)  Но всё это попахивает жареным (плохим кодом).

Answer (score 0):

Эм.. Никак?

Инстансная переменная своя у каждого экземпляра. Да её вообще может не быть, если ни одного экземпляра не создано.

Статическая функция наследника не имеет никаких экземпляров - так откуда же ей взять экземпларное значение?